# EditPlus autocomplete when press Spacebar

Tags: html

hy!

I searched the Net for EditPlus specific **forum** but I found only groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/editplus with zero activity. If someone know one please tell me.

Sometime I want to put some attribut in html tag e.g. `<p style="color:red">`

but after `<p` when I press space the autocomplete works and autocloses the tag. I want to swich off the **space tab** from autocomplete, let's autocomplete to works only when I press **enter**. How can I do this ?

An another problem is I want *"close html tag automaticaly"* enabled but in this case after `<p` followed by Enter I get:
`<p ></p>>`

Is any chance to escape from **last angle bracket** without disable  "close html tag automaticaly" option?

Comment: Under `Tools>Preferences` then `File>Settings&syntax`, each filetype has its own `Auto Completion` setting. You can turn it off (or on) there.

Comment: I know this setting, I have the correct path in this section and it work fine but I have the problem described above when I press Spacebar.

Comment: I want autocompletion only when I press Enter, not for Spacebar too!